# SQL using match on multiple tables (with join)

Tags: sql

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id

WHERE MATCH(b.title,b.article) AGAINST ('$search')

");
```

This produces the error "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list"

But either of these will work...

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id

WHERE MATCH(b.title) AGAINST ('$search')

");



mysql_query("SELECT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id

WHERE MATCH(b.article) AGAINST ('$search')

");
```

Text indexing is activated on all the columns that have been stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no FULLTEXT index on `b.title,b.article`.

Use your query as

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user_id=a.user_id

WHERE MATCH(b.title) AGAINST ('$search')
and
MATCH(b.article) AGAINST ('$search')

");
```

or build index on `b.title,b.article` columns

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX t_a_articles_index ON articles (title, article) ...
```

[How create index in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: As I have said all those columns have FULLTEXT indexing.

Comment: You need index on multiply columns. One index on 2 columns

Comment: Ok I tried this but get a syntax erorr? CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON articles(

`title` ,
`article` ,
`description`
)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include index_name. Edited my answer. Please try again

Comment: Do I have to have a separate MATCH statement for each table then?

Comment: If you build INDEX on two columns you may use `WHERE MATCH(b.title,b.article) AGAINST ('$search')`. Otherwise, you need to separate MATCH statement